# Will a Casio keyboard work with a lower current adapter?

Tags: keyboard

My electronic keyboard uses a 12V 2 ampere adapter.  Will it work with a 1 ampere adapter?

Comment: The linked previously answered question has a good writeup of the considerations, but to give you a quick answer: It probably won't fully work, but it might work as long as you don't turn the volume too high, and it *prabably* won't be damaged if you try it.

Comment: The adapter, however, could be damaged.